# Creating Azure table storage table failing

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-table-storage

I am following the [Get started with Azure Table storage using .NET](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/) tutorial with the following code in a console app to create a table:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("people");

table.CreateIfNotExists();
```

**Connection string in App.config**

```
<add key="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<accountName>;AccountKey=<accountKey>" />
```

I am getting this timeout error:

> {"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 92.242.132.16:443"}

**Stack trace:**

```
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 695
```

I have tried this several times in different new solutions, including an MVC web application but I get the same error each time.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. It could be an intermittent issue with your storage account? Please check Azure Status page for any issues in the region where your storage account is being hosted. Can you please try doing some other operation like creating a blob container?

Comment: Have you confirmed you have properly read-in a valid connection string? Maybe you could edit your question to show your connection string (obviously without the real name or key)?

Comment: @DavidMakogon thanks, I've updated my post

Comment: I’d like to know if you could connect to your azure account and create a table by using Azure Storage Explorer. Besides, [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/narahari/2011/12/21/azure-a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-did-not-properly-respond-after-a-period-of-time-or-established-connection-failed-because-connected-host-has-failed-to-respond-x-x-x-xx/) discussed a similar issue about “a connection attempt failed…”, you could read it. And you could try to run your program using the machine at another network to check if same issue could appear.